# linq-to-sql Concat() throwing a System.IndexOutofRangeException

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm struggling with an exception using linq-to-sql Concat()

I've got 2 tables.
The first table, ParsedMessages, has the following fields

```
* ParsedMessageID (int)
* MessageTypeID (int)
* TextMessage (varchar(max))
```

The second table, ParsedMessageLinks, has the following fields

```
* ParsedMessageID (int)
* AnotherID (int)
* NumberOfOccurences (int)
```

This is what I need to achieve using a single linq query but I'm not sure if it's possible or not.

- Through a join, retrieves ParsedMessage records that links to a certain AnotherID. In example SQL and linq code, the AnotherID will have the value 0 just for the purpose of having an example.
- For each ParsedMessage record, I also need the NumberOfOccurences (field of table #2)
- Retrieve only the top(100) ParsedMessage records for each MessageTypeID. So for example, if there is 275 records in ParsedMessages that links to AnotherID==0 where the first 150 records have MessageTypeID == 0 and the remaining 125 records having MessageTypeID == 1, I want my query to end up returning 200 records, the top(100) with MessageTypeID == 0 and the top(100) with MessageTypeID == 1

After a lot of search, I've found that the plain SQL equivalent of I what I want to do is this. I knew that this exists first end, but I tried to find something else without Union all at first and fail to do so (my SQL knowledge is not that good) :

> SELECT TOP(100) PM.*,
>   PML.NumberOfOccurences FROM
>   ParsedMessages PM INNER JOIN
>   ParsedMessageLinks PML ON
>   PM.ParsedMessageID =
>   PML.ParsedMessageID WHERE
>   PML.AnotherID = 0 AND PM.MessageTypeID
>   = 0 ORDER BY PM.ParsedMessageID DESC UNION ALL
>
> SELECT TOP(100) PM.*,
>   PML.NumberOfOccurences FROM
>   ParsedMessages PM INNER JOIN
>   ParsedMessageLinks PML ON
>   PM.ParsedMessageID =
>   PML.ParsedMessageID WHERE
>   PML.AnotherID = 0 AND PM.MessageTypeID
>   = 1 ORDER BY PM.ParsedMessageID DESC UNION ALL
>
> SELECT TOP(100) PM.*,
>   PML.NumberOfOccurences FROM
>   ParsedMessages PM INNER JOIN
>   ParsedMessageLinks PML ON
>   PM.ParsedMessageID =
>   PML.ParsedMessageID WHERE
>   PML.AnotherID = 0 AND PM.MessageTypeID
>   = 2 ORDER BY PM.ParsedMessageID DESC

So basically, the only way to retrieve the data I need is to do 3 sql queries in a single pass where only the PM.MessageTypeID is different for each query.

Now I wanted to achieve this using linq-to-sql. After googling, I've found that I could use the Linq Concat() method to reproduce a SQL Union All.
Here are some links pointing to what I thought would work :
http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2007/08/linq-to-sql-difference-between-concat.html

[EF. How to union tables, sort rows, and get top entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293404/ef-how-to-union-tables-sort-rows-and-get-top-entities)

I end up having this exception :
System.IndexOutOfRangeException : "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Here's the faulty code :

```
IQueryable<MyObject> concatquery;
int[] allMessageTypeIDs = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
for (int mt = 0; mt < allMessageTypeIDs.Length; mt++)
{
    if (mt == 0)
    {
        concatquery = (from pm in db.ParsedMessages
                       join pml in db.ParsedMessageLinks on pm.ParsedMessageID equals pml.ParsedMessageID
                       where pml.AnotherID == 0 && pm.MessageTypeID == allMessageTypeIDs[mt]
                       orderby pm.ParsedMessageID descending
                       select new MyObject
                       {
                           NumberOfOccurences = pml.Occurrences,
                           ParsedMessage = pm
                       }).Take(100);
    }
    else
    {
        concatquery = concatquery.Concat(from pm in db.ParsedMessages
                                        join pml in db.ParsedMessageLinks on pm.ParsedMessageID equals pml.ParsedMessageID
                                        where pml.AnotherID == 0 && pm.MessageTypeID == allMessageTypeIDs[mt]
                                        orderby pm.ParsedMessageID descending
                                        select new MyObject
                                        {
                                            NumberOfOccurences = pml.Occurrences,
                                            ParsedMessage = pm
                                        }).Take(100);
    }
}
var results = concatquery.ToArray();
```

I've declared the int array allMessageTypeIDs, for simplicity. But remember that the values it holds may differ, so that's why I've added the for loop. Maybe it's "illegal" to use a Concat() in a loop that way, but I could not find any relevant information on this exception.

The class MyObject basically hold a int (NumberOfOccurences) and a ParsedMessage database object, nothing else.

Any suggestions on what could be wrong with my code that causes the exception?

Thanks
Francis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use the variable you're looping with in your Linq queries.  It just doesn't work.  You want to assign a new temporary variable to use instead.

```
IQueryable<MyObject> concatquery;
int[] allMessageTypeIDs = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
for (int mt = 0; mt < allMessageTypeIDs.Length; mt++)
{
    var myItem = allMessageTypeIDs[mt]; // <-- HERE!
    if (mt == 0)
    {
        concatquery = (from pm in db.ParsedMessages
                       join pml in db.ParsedMessageLinks on pm.ParsedMessageID equals pml.ParsedMessageID
                       where pml.AnotherID == 0 && pm.MessageTypeID == myItem
                       orderby pm.ParsedMessageID descending
                       select new MyObject
                       {
                           NumberOfOccurences = pml.Occurrences,
                           ParsedMessage = pm
                       }).Take(100);
    }
    else
    {
        concatquery = concatquery.Concat(from pm in db.ParsedMessages
                                        join pml in db.ParsedMessageLinks on pm.ParsedMessageID equals pml.ParsedMessageID
                                        where pml.AnotherID == 0 && pm.MessageTypeID == myItem
                                        orderby pm.ParsedMessageID descending
                                        select new MyObject
                                        {
                                            NumberOfOccurences = pml.Occurrences,
                                            ParsedMessage = pm
                                        }).Take(100);
    }
}
var results = concatquery.ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 nice catch - also see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx for a more detailed explanation

Comment: Thanks for the link... I was searching for a few myself.  I think this is the single most common mistake people make with Linq.  Jon Skeet has nailed this one here a hundred times - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295593/linq-query-built-in-foreach-loop-always-takes-parameter-value-from-last-iteration